# semicolons or not in Matlab / Octave function bodies?

Tags: matlab, octave

Consider the following two functions in Octave / Matlab; the only difference between them is whether the lines in the body end with semicolons:

```
function [a, b, c] = fooNoSemicolons (x, y, z)
  a = x * 42
  b = y + 42
  c = (x * y) / (z * 42)
endfunction

function [a, b, c] = fooSemicolons (x, y, z)
  a = x * 42;
  b = y + 42;
  c = (x * y) / (z * 42);
endfunction
```

Now consider the following invocations and their outputs:

```
fprintf ("no semicolons: \n"); disp (fooNoSemicolons (12, 13, 14));
fprintf ("done\n");
fprintf ("semicolons:    \n"); disp (fooSemicolons (12, 13, 14));
fprintf ("done\n");
```

> ```
> no semicolons:
> a =  504
> b =  55
> c =  0.26531
>  504
> done
> semicolons:
>  504
> done
> ```

Clearly, both functions produce the same answer, the value of a, namely 504, but I don't quite see whether there is something semantically different going on inside.

I've not been able to find documentation about the meaning of semicolon in Matlab / Octave, but I have done a few more experiments that don't shed much light:

```
fprintf ("noSemicolons: \n");
[someA, someB, someC] = fooNoSemicolons (12, 13, 14);
fprintf ("done\n"); 
disp ([someA, someB, someC]);

fprintf ("semicolons:\n");
[moreA, moreB, moreC] = fooSemicolons (12, 13, 14);
fprintf ("done\n");
disp ([moreA, moreB, moreC]);

fprintf ("noSemicolons: \n");
otherStuff = fooNoSemicolons (12, 13, 14);
% otherStuff apparently does not get bound to an array or vector!
disp (otherStuff);
fprintf ("done\n"); 

fprintf ("semicolons:\n");
moreStuff  = fooSemicolons (12, 13, 14);
% moreStuff apparently does not get bound to an array or vector!
fprintf ("done\n"); 
disp (moreStuff);
```

> ```
> noSemicolons:
> a =  504
> b =  55
> c =  0.26531
> done
>    504.00000    55.00000     0.26531
> semicolons:
> done
>    504.00000    55.00000     0.26531
> noSemicolons:
> a =  504
> b =  55
> c =  0.26531
>  504
> done
> semicolons:
> done
>  504
> ```

Comment: Type `help punct` in your command window. This is something one normally learns in the first five minutes of learning Matlab.

Comment: It looks like your question has been answered correctly. Just so you know, if you're using a licensed copy of MATLAB then you should have access to a free 2-hour online training course through your MATLAB account. It gives a good overview of the basics, including the semicolon.

Comment: I'm using octave, but trying to stay within the Matlab subset of it.  I'm working with code generated from a DSL, so diving right into the deep end and figuring it out in an inside-out manner, not from the top like a student.

Comment: @horchler `help punct` didn't work in Octave, sadly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting a semicolon at the end of line of Matlab/Octave code prevents the console from printing the answer/variable assignment/whatever.

```
x=5
```

Sets x to 5 and prints the value of x.

```
x=5;
```

Sets x to 5.